# What device can I use to parallel 4 dry contact signals from 4 timer relays

Tags: timer, multiplexer, solenoid-valve, latching-relay

What device can I use to multiplex 4 dry contact signals from 4 timer relays to  actuate an isolation valve? In other words, any of the signals from the timer relay should be able to actuate the isolation valve, it could be more than one timer relay that is activate, but the isolation valve will see only one signal which it needs to actuate the valve.

Comment: What is the consumption current of the valve? Do you have a basic schematic?

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFITzt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. All relay contacts are wired in OR configuration. Any one turning on will energise the solenoid vlave.*

Note that this is not multiplexing which is generally a method by which multiple analog or digital signals are combined into one signal over a shared medium with the intention of extracting the original individual signals at the far end.

Answer (score 0):

Put the four output contacts from your relay's in parallel, source on one side, load on the other.  Done.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use a 1 pole, 4 way rotary switch.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You need a 4-input OR gate. Exact part number depends on voltage of your signals, operating conditions, etc.